# List of all classification algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a classification problem and I would like to test all the available algorithms to test their performance in tackling the problem.

If you know any classification algorithm other than these listed below, please list it here.

```
GradientBoostingClassifier()
DecisionTreeClassifier()
RandomForestClassifier()
LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
LogisticRegression()
KNeighborsClassifier()
GaussianNB()
ExtraTreesClassifier()
BaggingClassifier()
```

Comment: Asking for a list of all classification algorithms is too broad - the number will be huge. For a list of all classification algorithms currently available in scikit-learn you can go through "supervised learning" in the scikit-learn docs. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html You missed e.g. SVM and neural networks.

Comment: The list of all classification algorithms will be huge. But you may ask for the most popular algorithms for classification. For any classification task, first try the simple (linear) methods of logistic regression, Naive Bayes, linear SVM, decision trees, etc, then try non-linear methods of SVM using RBF kernel, ensemble methods like Random forests, gradient boosted trees etc, then try advanced methods like deep learning.

Comment: Classification in what context? In some specific machine learning context? For some particular machine learning library? How broad is the scope of this question? It is far from clear if the tags provide a hint for this or not. Can you [make it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41844311/edit) clearer in the body of the question?  (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The answers did not provide the full list of classifiers, so I have listed them below.

```
from sklearn.tree import ExtraTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm.classes import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors.classification import RadiusNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors.classification import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.multioutput import ClassifierChain
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OutputCodeClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model.ridge import RidgeClassifierCV
from sklearn.linear_model.ridge import RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model.passive_aggressive import PassiveAggressiveClassifier    
from sklearn.gaussian_process.gpc import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.voting_classifier import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.weight_boosting import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.bagging import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelPropagation
from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelSpreading
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB  
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestCentroid
from sklearn.svm import NuSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.mixture import DPGMM
from sklearn.mixture import GMM 
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.mixture import VBGMM
```

Answer (score 21):

You may want to look at the following question:

[How to list all scikit-learn classifiers that support predict_proba()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056331/how-to-list-all-scikit-learn-classifiers-that-support-predict-proba)

The accepted answer shows the method to get all estimators in scikit which support **predict_probas** method. Just iterate and print all names without checking the condition and you get all estimators. (Classifiers, regressors, cluster etc)

For only classifiers, modify it like below to check all classes that implement [ClassifierMixin](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin.html)

```
from sklearn.base import ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators
classifiers=[est for est in all_estimators() if issubclass(est[1], ClassifierMixin)]
print(classifiers)
```

For versions >= 0.22, use [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.all_estimators.html#sklearn-utils-all-estimators):

```
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators
```

instead of `sklearn.utils.testing`

Points to note:

- The classifiers with **CV** suffixed to their names implement inbuilt cross-validation (like LogisticRegressionCV, RidgeClassifierCV etc).
- Some are ensemble and may take other classifiers in input arguments.
- Some classifiers like **_QDA**, **_LDA** are aliases for other classifiers and may be removed in next versions of scikit-learn.

You should check their respective reference docs before using them

Comment: \deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.utils.testing module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.utils. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.utils is now part of the private API.

Comment: @celsowm I have updated the answer. Thanks for informing.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to use the module `from sklearn.utils import all_estimators`. Here's an example for importing all classifiers:

```py
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators

estimators = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')

all_clfs = []
for name, ClassifierClass in estimators:
    print('Appending', name)
    try:
        clf = ClassifierClass()
        all_clfs.append(clf)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to import', name)
        print(e)
```

[Here's Colaboratory code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qlATTxRHGIV1lzjcAsAIvMyc-SyxqpBm?usp=sharing) with it working.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'base_estimator'

Comment: You have to be careful because some of the naive bayes models can only take certain types of features. e.g. the CategoricalNB model can only take non-negative integer values as features.

Comment: Yeah, the main point here is to make everyone aware of the module `from sklearn.utils import all_estimators`, however, each estimator has to be treated carefully.

Comment: The following classifiers cannot be instantiated in the Colab notebook:

Appending ClassifierChain
Unable to import ClassifierChain
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'base_estimator'

Unable to import MultiOutputClassifier
Unable to import OneVsOneClassifier
Unable to import OneVsRestClassifier
Unable to import OutputCodeClassifier
Unable to import StackingClassifier
Unable to import VotingClassifier
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'estimators'

Answer (score 0):

Some code from Shaheer Akram answer is deprecated, so you can get actual import code with it (sklearn 1.0.2):

```
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators

estimators = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
for name, class_ in estimators:
    module_name = str(class_).split("'")[1].split(".")[1]
    class_name = class_.__name__
    print(f'from sklearn.{module_name} import {class_name}')
```

Output

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import CategoricalNB
from sklearn.multioutput import ClassifierChain
from sklearn.naive_bayes import ComplementNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
from sklearn.tree import ExtraTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelPropagation
from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelSpreading
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestCentroid
from sklearn.svm import NuSVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OutputCodeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.neighbors import RadiusNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifierCV
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
```

## List of classification estimators

```
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators

estimators = all_estimators(type_filter='classifier')
i = 0
for name, class_ in estimators:
    print(f'{i}. {class_.__name__}')
    i += 1
```

**Output (41 estimators)**

0. AdaBoostClassifier
1. BaggingClassifier
2. BernoulliNB
3. CalibratedClassifierCV
4. CategoricalNB
5. ClassifierChain
6. ComplementNB
7. DecisionTreeClassifier
8. DummyClassifier
9. ExtraTreeClassifier
10. ExtraTreesClassifier
11. GaussianNB
12. GaussianProcessClassifier
13. GradientBoostingClassifier
14. HistGradientBoostingClassifier
15. KNeighborsClassifier
16. LabelPropagation
17. LabelSpreading
18. LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
19. LinearSVC
20. LogisticRegression
21. LogisticRegressionCV
22. MLPClassifier
23. MultiOutputClassifier
24. MultinomialNB
25. NearestCentroid
26. NuSVC
27. OneVsOneClassifier
28. OneVsRestClassifier
29. OutputCodeClassifier
30. PassiveAggressiveClassifier
31. Perceptron
32. QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
33. RadiusNeighborsClassifier
34. RandomForestClassifier
35. RidgeClassifier
36. RidgeClassifierCV
37. SGDClassifier
38. SVC
39. StackingClassifier
40. VotingClassifier