# How to list all classification/regression/clustering algorithms in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In analogy to [How to list all scikit-learn classifiers that support predict_proba()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056331/how-to-list-all-scikit-learn-classifiers-that-support-predict-proba) I want to retrieve a list of all classification/regression/clustering algorithms currently supported in scikit-learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844311/list-of-all-classification-algorithms/41853264#41853264

Comment: Did you read my question? This is exactly what I am referring to and pointing out the difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Combining [How to list all scikit-learn classifiers that support predict_proba()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056331/how-to-list-all-scikit-learn-classifiers-that-support-predict-proba) and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.base yields the solution:

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators
from sklearn import base

estimators = all_estimators()

for name, class_ in estimators:
    if issubclass(class_, base.ClassifierMixin):
        print(name)
```

Or use any other base class: ClusterMixin, RegressorMixin, TransformerMixin.

Answer (score 5):

As a more up-to-date solution, sklearn updated the module to [sklearn.utils.all_estimators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.all_estimators.html). Here's an example for importing all regression models:

```py
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators

estimators = all_estimators(type_filter='regressor')

all_regs = []
for name, RegressorClass in estimators:
    try:
        print('Appending', name)
        reg = RegressorClass()
        all_regs.append(reg)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Some of them require an init parameter (like estimator) and had to be ignored using try..except.