# How can I import all of sklearns regressors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import

I'm doing some predictive modeling and would like to benchmark different kinds of regressors in `scikit-learn`, just to see what's out there and how they perform on a given prediction task.

I got inspired to do this by this [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/yassineghouzam/titanic-top-4-with-ensemble-modeling) in which the author essentially manually imports a bunch of classifiers (about 10) and benchmarks them.

I'm having trouble finding a comprehensive list of imports for the regressors in `sklearn` so I'm trying to automatize the `import` statements to automatically return me a list of classes that I can use.

I tried to dynamically import the classes:

```
from importlib import import_module
import sklearn

def all_regressors():
    regressors=[]
    for module in sklearn.__all__:
        try:
            regressors.extend([cls for cls in import_module(f'sklearn.{module}').__all__ if 'Regress' in cls ])
        except:
            pass
    regressors.append(sklearn.svm.SVR)
    return regressors
print(all_regressors())
```

But i only get back the names as strings, rather than the classes:

```
['RandomForestRegressor', 'ExtraTreesRegressor', 'BaggingRegressor',
'GradientBoostingRegressor', 'AdaBoostRegressor', 
'GaussianProcessRegressor', 'IsotonicRegression', 'ARDRegression', 
'HuberRegressor', 'LinearRegression', 'LogisticRegression', 
'LogisticRegressionCV', 'PassiveAggressiveRegressor', 
'RandomizedLogisticRegression', 'SGDRegressor', 'TheilSenRegressor', 
'RANSACRegressor', 'MultiOutputRegressor', 'KNeighborsRegressor', 
'RadiusNeighborsRegressor', 'MLPRegressor', 'DecisionTreeRegressor', 
'ExtraTreeRegressor', <class 'sklearn.svm.classes.SVR'>]
```

How can I get the actual classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all_estimators` from `sklearn.utils`

```py
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators

def get_all_regressors_sklearn():

    estimators = all_estimators(type_filter='regressor')

    all_regs = []
    for name, RegClass in estimators:
        print('Appending', name)
        try:
            reg = RegClass()
            all_regs.append(reg)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    return all_regs

all_regs = get_all_regressors_sklearn()
print(all_regs)
```

Gives:

```
[ARDRegression(), AdaBoostRegressor(), BaggingRegressor(), BayesianRidge(), CCA(), DecisionTreeRegressor(), DummyRegressor(), ElasticNet(), ElasticNetCV(), ExtraTreeRegressor(), ExtraTreesRegressor(), GammaRegressor(), GaussianProcessRegressor(), GradientBoostingRegressor(), HistGradientBoostingRegressor(), HuberRegressor(), IsotonicRegression(), KNeighborsRegressor(), KernelRidge(), Lars(), LarsCV(), Lasso(), LassoCV(), LassoLars(), LassoLarsCV(), LassoLarsIC(), LinearRegression(), LinearSVR(), MLPRegressor(), MultiTaskElasticNet(), MultiTaskElasticNetCV(), MultiTaskLasso(), MultiTaskLassoCV(), NuSVR(), OrthogonalMatchingPursuit(), OrthogonalMatchingPursuitCV(), PLSCanonical(), PLSRegression(), PassiveAggressiveRegressor(), PoissonRegressor(), QuantileRegressor(), RANSACRegressor(), RadiusNeighborsRegressor(), RandomForestRegressor(), Ridge(), RidgeCV(), SGDRegressor(), SVR(), TheilSenRegressor(), TransformedTargetRegressor(), TweedieRegressor()]
```

Comment: Very cool, marked as correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out i had to use `getattr` on the module object:

```
from importlib import import_module
import sklearn

def all_regressors():
    regressors=[]
    for module in sklearn.__all__:
        try:
            module = import_module(f'sklearn.{module}')
            regressors.extend([getattr(module,cls) for cls in module.__all__  if 'Regress' in cls ])
        except:
            pass
    regressors.append(sklearn.svm.SVR)
    return regressors
print(all_regressors())
```

```
[<class 'sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.ensemble.forest.ExtraTreesRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.ensemble.bagging.BaggingRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting.GradientBoostingRegressor'>,
<class 'sklearn.ensemble.weight_boosting.AdaBoostRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.gaussian_process.gpr.GaussianProcessRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.isotonic.IsotonicRegression'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.bayes.ARDRegression'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.huber.HuberRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.base.LinearRegression'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegressionCV'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.passive_aggressive.PassiveAggressiveRegressor'>, 
<class 'sklearn.linear_model.randomized_l1.RandomizedLogisticRegression'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient.SGDRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.theil_sen.TheilSenRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.linear_model.ransac.RANSACRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.neighbors.regression.KNeighborsRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.neighbors.regression.RadiusNeighborsRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron.MLPRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.tree.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.tree.tree.ExtraTreeRegressor'>, <class 
'sklearn.svm.classes.SVR'>]
```

Comment: Do all the regressors have "Regress" in the name?

Comment: No not all of them. SVR doesn't

Comment: Some regressors seem to be missing from this list, e.g. Ridge and KernelRidge. A more complete is given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42160314/2629879