# Which estimators in scikit-learn support `partial_fit` API?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Only examples of estimators that implement the `partial_fit` API that I can find are `SGDRegressor` and `SGDClassifier`.  Are there others? Is there a list of estimators that implement the `partial_fit` API?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064773/2315949 (works just as well with partial_fit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of models that allows `partial_fit()`.

[Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning)

> **Classification**
>
> sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB
> sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron
> sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier
> sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier
>
> **Regression**
>
> sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor
> sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor
>
> **Clustering**
>
> sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans
>
> **Decomposition / feature Extraction**
>
> sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchDictionaryLearning
> sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans