# How to find all sparse data regressors in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

You can [find all regressors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.testing.all_estimators.html) in scikit-learn with:

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators
regressors = all_estimators(type_filter='regressor')
```

However, my data is sparse, and I'm finding that many of these don't support sparse data. I could brute-force evaluate all of them and exclude those that fail, but is there an easier way to tell in advance which don't support sparsity?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that. You are better off checking the documentation for `fit()` as specified in this question:

- [Which estimators in scikit-learn don't support sparse matrices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22737053/3374996)

or else use `try catch block` to handle that.

Most estimators (regressors or classifiers) will check the validate the inputs by calling [`check_X_y`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_X_y.html) with appropriate parameters. The parameter of our interest is `**'accept_sparse'**` which is by default `False`. So if an estimator calls this method without any value for `'accept_sparse'` can be safely assumed to not support sparse matrices.

You can use the following code for part of the problem.

```
import inspect 
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators 
regressors = all_estimators(type_filter='regressor')

for regressor in regressors:
    print(regressor[0], end=" - ")
    ff = getattr(regressor[1], 'fit')
    if 'accept_sparse' in inspect.getsource(ff):
        print('Accepts Sparse')
    else:
        print("Does not")
```

- If the output has "**Accepts Sparse**", then you can be sure that it can handle the sparse data.
- But if the output has "**Does not**", then it only means that the source code for `fit()`:-

  - Does not contain the `check_X_y`: This does not mean that the sparse data is not supported. Maybe the current estimator is calling a different parent class's `fit()` which have that check. Some estimators having `CV` in the end are cross-validators which again pass the data to base estimators and hence may not perform the check.
  - It maybe does not contain the parameter "`accept_sparse`" explicitly: The source code may have something like `check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc', 'coo'], ...)`. Depending upon the possible accepted values for `accept_sparse`, it may not be easily found out.

  So in that case, you can use the try-catch to find the actual status.